# How to check If row exist in insert statement where inserting valuse using implode and array()

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have an insert statement to insert data into my database by implode() an array

```
$sql->prepared("INSERT INTO student(studentId,studentemail,phone,address)VALUE".implode(',', array());
```

The problem is every time I run the script I have to delete every row from my database because my array already have the values stored in the database plus the new values which I want to insert. So, I want to implement an query in which if existed don't Insert. I am not sure how to play with it.

Comment: `VALUE` should be `VALUES`. You also need to put quotes around each of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `insert on duplicate key`.  First you need a unique index.  I am guessing:

```
create unique index unq_student_studentid on student(studentid);

insert into student (studentId, studentemail, phone, address)
     value . . .
     on duplicate key studentid = values(studentid);
```

This will ignore existing data.  Using the same method, you can also update the other fields, if you prefer the newer values.

That said, inserting the data every time seems like a poorly designed application.

Comment: But, How can I create a unique index in php. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create a unique index on `studentid` (it probably should already be the primary key) and then use `INSERT IGNORE` instead of ordinary `INSERT`. This just skips any rows that would violate the unique constraint.

Comment: You don't do that in PHP, you do it in the database. Gordon's answer shows the syntax.